# Tradução de Looks OK

Tags: bug, status-pronto, tradução, internacionalização

Acho que ainda ninguém reparou mais este botão está por traduzir:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: No dia que trocaram o texto de "looks good" pra "looks ok" eu avisei o Gabe. Parece que os devs precisam criar uma nova chave no dicionário de tradução, enquanto isso o Gabe não tem como colocar a versão em português. Bom você ter registrado o bug, pra ele se lembrar disso.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The code was configured to translate as soon as the translation is provided. No code changes to make, only data to be added. It will be added in the near future and then it will appear translated correctly.

**I don't speak Portuguese so Google Translate:**

O código foi configurado para traduzir logo que a tradução é fornecida. Não há alterações no código para fazer, apenas dados a serem adicionados. Ele será adicionado em um futuro próximo e então a tradução aparecerá corretamente.

Comment: Perhaps you could post both in English and Portuguese. Google translate is not reliable and if in some occasions it fails to translate properly we can make some adjustments :)

Comment: @Math done, thanks!

Comment: Somehow Google managed to translate "it will appear translated correctly" as "and then look right", LOL.

Comment: Close enough for rock and roll. ;)